# Translucent circular Control with text

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, transparency, gdi+

I am working on a project wherein I need to add a Control with the shape of a Circle with some text in the middle.
My problem is the circle is too small, when I resize it, it overlaps other controls. I want to draw the circle same width as the square.
Otherwise. how can I make the Control's background transparent?

[image]

I am using the code below:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height))
    {
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            graphics.Clear(this.BackColor);

            using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(this._FillColor))
            {                      
                graphics.FillEllipse(brush, 0x18 - 6, 0x18 - 6, (this.Width - 0x30) + 12, (this.Height - 0x30) + 12);
            }

            Brush FontColor = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor);
            SizeF MS = graphics.MeasureString(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32((100 / _Maximum) * _Value)), Font);
            graphics.DrawString(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32((100 / _Maximum) * _Value)), Font, FontColor, Convert.ToInt32((Width / 2 - MS.Width / 2) + 2), Convert.ToInt32((Height / 2 - MS.Height / 2) + 3));
            bitmap.MakeTransparent(this.BackColor);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);

            graphics.Dispose();
            bitmap.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you're making the circle too small. Have you tried increasing values of `graphics.FillEllipse`?

Comment: Your circle is exactly as big as I expect it to be based on your code. Your problem is that you're drawing it at 18, 18 with the approximate size 41x41, but you want it to be 0, 0 with approximate size 77x77. It seems to me that all you need is `graphics.FillEllipse(brush, e.ClipRectangle);` without all the extra `Bitmap` stuff, etc.

Comment: @john Thanks, that works fine. But i did not remove the Bitmap thing, when i remove that, the circle is not showing.

Comment: I meant that why don't you just use `e.Graphics` rather than creating a bitmap, creating an instance of `Graphics` for the bitmap, drawing everything onto that before finally using `e.Graphics` to draw it to the control?

Comment: Another issue, If I resize the circle, the font is not resizing. How will I do it?

Comment: In winforms there is no such thing as 'a circle'. There are only controls with surfaces consisting of pixels. And bitmaps.We have no idea what you want to do. So there really is not advice what to do best. To place a text centered in a bitmap you should: use TextRenderer.DrawText not Graphics.DrawString b) draw into a rectangle c) use centered  StringFormat.

Comment: Also: You can use graphics.Clear(Color.Transparent) to start with a transparent bitmap instead of using the notorious MakeTransparent, which will miss all anti-aliased pixels.. But most important you need to know what you really want to achieve. If you do: TELL US

Comment: @TaW, ok thanks. I am doing a custom control `public class CircularLabel : Control` Then I use the code above to `Paint` it. The text is already centered and the Circle is now okay. The remaining issue is when I resize the Circle, the font is not resizing.

Comment: OK, so all you need it to change the Font. You will have to find some formula to determine the new Height, then write: `using (Font font = new Font(Font.FontFamily, newHeight)) TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics,text, font, ... );` Do avoid graphics.DrawString for [TextRenderer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h60yx8s5(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 12):

This is a Custom Control derived from `Control`, which can be made translucent.
The interface is a colored circle which can contain a couple of numbers.

The Control exposes these custom properties:

**`Opacity`**: The level of opacity of the control `BackGround` `[0, 255]`
**`InnerPadding`**: The distance between the inner rectangle, which defines the circle bounds and the control bounds.
**`FontPadding`**: The distance between the Text and the Inner rectangle.

Transparency is obtained overriding [CreateParams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.createparams), then setting `ExStyle |= WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;`

The [Control.SetStyle()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.setstyle) method is used to modify the control behavior, adding these [ControlStyles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.controlstyles):

▶ **`ControlStyles.Opaque`**: prevents the painting of a Control's BackGround, so it's not managed by the System. Combined with CreateParams to set the Control's Extended Style to `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT`, the Control becomes completely transparent.

▶ **`ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor`** the control accepts Alpha values for it's `BackGround` color. Without also setting `ControlStyles.UserPaint` it won't be used to simulate transparency. We're doing that ourselves with other means.

---

To see it at work, create a new Class file, substitute all the code inside with this code **preserving the NameSpace** and build the Project/Solution.
The new Custom Control will appear in the ToolBox. Drop it on a Form. Modify its custom properties as needed.

A visual representation of the control:

[image: WinForms Translucent Label]

**Note and disclaimer**:

- This is a prototype Control, the custom Designer is missing (cannot post that here, too much code, also connected to a framework).
  As presented here, it can be used to **completely** overlap other Controls in a Form or other containers. Partial overlapping is not handled in this simplified implementation.
- The Font is hard-coded to `Segoe UI`, since this Font has a base-line that simplifies the position of the text in the middle of the circular area.
  Other Fonts have a different base-line, which requires more complex handling.
  See: [TextBox with dotted lines for typing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64673192/7444103) for the base math.

---

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[DesignerCategory("Code")]
public class RoundCenterLabel : Label, INotifyPropertyChanged, ISupportInitialize 
{
    private const int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x00000020;
    private bool IsInitializing = false;
    private Point MouseDownLocation = Point.Empty;
    private readonly int fontPadding = 4;
    private Font m_CustomFont = null;
    private Color m_BackGroundColor;
    private int m_InnerPadding = 0;
    private int m_FontPadding = 25;
    private int m_Opacity = 128;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public RoundCenterLabel() => InitializeComponent();

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque |
                 ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor |
                 ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, false);
        m_CustomFont = new Font("Segoe UI", 50, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
        ForeColor = Color.White;
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
        get {
            var cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
            return cp;
        }
    }

    public new Font Font
    {
        get => m_CustomFont;
        set { 
            m_CustomFont = value;
            if (IsInitializing) return;
            FontAdapter(value, DeviceDpi);
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public override string Text {
        get => base.Text;
        set { base.Text = value;
              NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int InnerPadding {
        get => m_InnerPadding;
        set {
            if (IsInitializing) return;
            m_InnerPadding = ValidateRange(value, 0, ClientRectangle.Height - 10);
            NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public int FontPadding {
        get => m_FontPadding;
        set {
            if (IsInitializing) return;
            m_FontPadding = ValidateRange(value, 0, ClientRectangle.Height - 10);
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int Opacity {
        get => m_Opacity;
        set { m_Opacity = ValidateRange(value, 0, 255);
              UpdateBackColor(m_BackGroundColor);
              NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public override Color BackColor {
        get => m_BackGroundColor;
        set { UpdateBackColor(value);
              NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLayout(e);
        base.AutoSize = false;
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
    {
        InvalidateParent();
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
            var loc = new Point(Left + (e.X - MouseDownLocation.X), Top + (e.Y - MouseDownLocation.Y));
            InvalidateParent();
            BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Location = loc));
        }
    }

    private void InvalidateParent()
    {
        Parent?.Invalidate(Bounds, true);
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var format = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit | StringFormatFlags.NoWrap, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.LCID))
        {
            format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;

            using (var circleBrush = new SolidBrush(m_BackGroundColor))
            using (var foreBrush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor))
            {
                FontAdapter(m_CustomFont, e.Graphics.DpiY);
                RectangleF rect = InnerRectangle();
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(circleBrush, rect);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, m_CustomFont, foreBrush, rect, format);
            };
        };
    }

    public void BeginInit() => IsInitializing = true;

    public void EndInit()
    {
        IsInitializing = false;
        Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 50, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        FontPadding = m_FontPadding;
        InnerPadding = m_InnerPadding;
    }

    private RectangleF InnerRectangle()
    {
        (float Min, _) = GetMinMax(ClientRectangle.Height, ClientRectangle.Width);
        var size = new SizeF(Min - (m_InnerPadding / 2), Min - (m_InnerPadding / 2));
        var position = new PointF((ClientRectangle.Width - size.Width) / 2,
                                  (ClientRectangle.Height - size.Height) / 2);
        return new RectangleF(position, size);
    }

    private void FontAdapter(Font font, float dpi)
    {
        RectangleF rect = InnerRectangle();
        float fontSize = ValidateRange(
            (int)(rect.Height - m_FontPadding), 6, 
            (int)(rect.Height - m_FontPadding)) / (dpi / 72.0F) - fontPadding;

        m_CustomFont.Dispose();
        m_CustomFont = new Font(font.FontFamily, fontSize, font.Style, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }

    private void UpdateBackColor(Color color)
    {
        m_BackGroundColor = Color.FromArgb(m_Opacity, Color.FromArgb(color.R, color.G, color.B));
        base.BackColor = m_BackGroundColor;
    }

    private int ValidateRange(int Value, int Min, int Max) 
        => Math.Max(Math.Min(Value, Max), Min); // (Value < Min) ? Min : ((Value > Max) ? Max : Value);

    private (float, float) GetMinMax(float Value1, float Value2) 
        => (Math.Min(Value1, Value2), Math.Max(Value1, Value2));
}
```