# C# windows form circular button smoothing by anti-aliasing

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm New in c sharp, i'm trying to make a circular button. the code below is making a ellipse for me but it is not looking smooth, also it is having partially hidden lines at right and bottom as shown in image
[image: ellipse button]

```
 class ButtonEllipse: Button
    {
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            GraphicsPath graphics = new GraphicsPath();
            Rectangle myEllipse = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.ClientSize.Width,this.ClientSize.Height);
            graphics.AddEllipse(myEllipse);            
            Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
            this.Region = new System.Drawing.Region(graphics);   
            base.OnPaint(e);
         }
     }
```

can you please guide me how to get a exact and smooth circular button.

Comment: No Regions, those are difficult to anti-alias. See the example here: [Translucent circle with text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51435842/7444103). You'll have to draw all the parts yourself, if you want a decent result (including the Button's states). You can probably do something similar using Images that reproduce the states (Default, Entered, Hot, Pressed).

Comment: Create and set the Region ONCE, or whenever the button changes size.  There is no need to do this every time it repaints itself...

Comment: You're also creating and LEAKING a Pen.  Create Pens/Brushes in a `using()` block so it correctly gets disposed of.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;` [Read more about antialiazing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/antialiasing-with-lines-and-curves).

You should perhaps also paint the button graphics directly rather than using the Region. See [DrawEllipse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawellipse?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) and [FillEllipse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.fillellipse?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1).