# Placing a Picture Box Over Another Picture Box

Tags: c#, winforms, tcp, tcpclient, chess

I am quite new at c#, and do not know much about the Microsoft Forms. Is there any way to place a picture box over another picture box? I am currently working on a TCP Chess project, so when i type, for example a2-c8, the pawn in a2 should move to c8. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtKpm.png) image shows the chess board I am using. I want the pawn to be placed over a picture box and to be able to move it through my input. Each cell is a different picture box(a1Tile, a2Tile...) Any idea how can i implement this? I am quite new so i do not know much about Microsoft Forms.

Comment: Yes, you can if you __nest__ them, which needs to be done in code. Note that transparency will not work well for overlapping child controls. There are many posts about this. Often the best advice is to draw inages of the pieces instead of using controls..

Comment: You'd better off drawing the board on a Control that acts as canvas and is the Parent (or it will be set as Parent) of your *chess pieces*, it's easier to handle transparency this way. Otherwise, you should build a [translucent Control like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51435842/7444103), which can overlap other Controls and  still remain translucent. It may be difficult to modify and adapt to your use-case if you don't know the WinForms platform that well.